# Automating the process of installing apps on a iOS device

Tags: ios

I want to know if there are any methods to automatically install apps on an iOS device? I do not want to install the app via iTunes.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Unless the phone is jailbroken or you're installing developer betas, all apps have to be installed via the App Store, whether directly on the device or through iTunes...

Comment: My requirement goes like this: I have a Jenkins build system that generates the build for my application. Now, i want to automatically install the app [ basically over the air installation ], without manual inter-action. Is this possiable?

Comment: Are you developing for jailbroken phones or standard iOS?

Comment: On a standard iOS device. Is it possible to do it? How is it done on a jailbroken device?

Comment: I'm not familiar with XCode and standard iOS development. On jailbroken iPhones it's done over SSH.

Comment: Could you please let me know how it is done on a jailbroken device? any link or documentation for it?

Comment: On a jailbroken iPhone you make a .deb package, SSH it over to the phone, unpackage and install it, and then restart Springboard. But that's all irrelevant to developing on standard iOS. This article: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices seems to cover automatic deployment of an iOS app from XCode, which is the best I know how to do.